# Is R Studio compatible with R 3.4.x?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have R 3.4.3 installed on my computer. When I point R Studio to this version of R, the program loads a white screen.

Is R Studio compatible with R 3.4.x? What is the highest version of compatibility?

Comment: Yes, it's compatible.  You've got something wrong with your install of R or RStudio.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330.
I don't think down voting was necessary. I did not find an answer elsewhere and had a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

It actually would depend on the version of Rstudio. For the latest ones - yes it is. If your Rstudio is outdated (version `0.*.*`) it might have problems with the newest versions of R.

The first step would be to check your R installation. Start R without Rstudio and see if it works. If it doesn't you need to re-install R. If R works fine, then reinstalling Rstudio might be the easiest solution.